# Why a simple Plot on Raspberry Pi 3 with Mathematica takes 20 seconds?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, system-performance

I'm with `ssh -X raspberrypi` logged in. So `$DISPLAY` points to a X-Server.
I use a very simple script file `script.m` with

```
Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]
```

I run this like

```
$ time wolfram -script script.m
```

, which gives me

```
real    0m21.314s
user    0m4.100s
sys     0m1.090s
```

If I run

```
Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

, it gives me:

```
real    0m2.930s
user    0m2.320s
sys     0m0.230s
```

, so almost 20 seconds faster than the plot with the option. I see a process `WolframFrontEnd` popping up in `top`, when i set the option `PlotLabels`.

So how to avoid that `wolfram` talks to the X Server? And why is this option dependent in `Plot`?